# dd count default

Tags: dd, defaults

What is the `count` default in `dd` command if not specified ?

```
dd if=/dev/mem bs=1k skip=768
```

instead of full form like

```
dd if=/dev/mem bs=1k skip=768 count=50
```

I did not find an answer with Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default is unlimited - keep going until you run out of space.

Comment: ... or out of input, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 5):

Count means amounts of blocks to copy. From man page:

```
count=N
      copy only N input blocks
```

It means amount of times to copy each block of input file. Block size specified by `bs` parameter.

If you wont to specify `count` parameter, dd will read-write until the end of input file. So, there is no default numberic value, only `EOF`.

Comment: JFI: EOF = End Of File